# How to specify a negative power of base 10?

Tags: cmath

I would like to enter values like z = 5e-3 (that is, z = 0.005) and w = 5e6 into my code.

I've looked through documentation on the `pow10` function, but of course something like  `double pow10(int -9);` isn't allowed.

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 for C++ on Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double z = 5e-3;
```

works, or alternatively

```
double z = 5*pow(10, -3);
```

(I presume you're using C, or C++. You didn't specify in the question or the tags; but the "cmath" tag was used.)

Comment: This is indeed low-hanging fruit for you, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I did have to write & compile something quickly to make sure I wasn't misremembering... but yes. :)